# concatenate talend rows into json string

Tags: java, etl, talend

I have a #Talend Job that returns data rows.  what I want to do is take those rows and concatenate them into a JSON String.

roles

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name  ║ person ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ admin ║ jon    ║
║  2 ║ admin ║ fred   ║
║  3 ║ user  ║ alfred ║
║  4 ║ user  ║ jon    ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

I'd like to get a JSON hash like so:

```
{"admin": 
  ["jon", "fred"], 
  "user": ["alfred", "jon"]
}
```

Is there a way to create a temp table or object and cycle through the records?  Right now I'm using a tHashoutput to store the data - how do I cycle through the records?  so i can output a JSON string every so many records.

For every 100 records, I want to create a JSON string.

Comment: It is very strange to get data not in one line. First of all try to solve this task.

Comment: you can use flat files or thashouput as you are using..then you can read from this flat file or thashoutput using tfileinput* or thashinput and iterate for every row or group them and then iterate..